# Set print composer to map canvas extent using python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

I have a QGIS python script which successfully loads a specified print composer template.

At the end of this script I have attempted to set the composer to the map canvas extent, but I receive the following error message:

AttributeError: 'QgsComposerView' object has no attribute 'getComposerItemById'

I'm running Windows 10, QGIS 2.14.7

The code is as follows:

```
import os,sys
from qgis.core import*
from PyQt4.QtCore import*
from qgis.utils import*
from qgis.gui import *
import qgis
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
layers = canvas.layers()

myFile = os.path.join('P:\Office Admin\GIS\Templates\Plan templates\QGIS template plans\Title deed templates', 'A0_landscape_title deed.qpt')
myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
myTemplateFile.close()
myDocument = QDomDocument()
myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent, False)
comp = iface.createNewComposer()
comp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)

map_item = comp.getComposerItemById('Map 1')
map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)
map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Stuart! Try replacing `map_item = comp.getComposerItemById('Map 1')` with `map_item = comp.composition().getComposerItemById('Map 1')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Joseph, that worked perfectly. I've shown the completed code below for reference.

```
import os,sys
from qgis.core import*
from PyQt4.QtCore import*
from qgis.utils import*
from qgis.gui import *
import qgis
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
layers = canvas.layers()

myFile = os.path.join('P:\Office Admin\GIS\Templates\Plan templates\QGIS template plans\Title deed templates', 'A0_landscape_title deed.qpt')
myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
myTemplateFile.close()
myDocument = QDomDocument()
myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent, False)
comp = iface.createNewComposer()
comp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)

map_item = comp.composition().getComposerItemById('Map 1')
map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)
map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())
```

Note: If you do not set the Item ID in the "Item properties - Item ID" panel and save this as part of your template before running the code, the following error will occur:

Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setMapCanvas'

Your Item ID should correspond to that specified in the code - for this example the Item ID is Map 1.

Comment: Alternatively, [`getComposerMapById(1)`](https://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsComposition.html#ab47c0e5b447ea79d0c8cc198bc69aeef)